# CodeWars mathematical expresion evaluator

Tags: ruby, programming-challenge, math-expression-eval

I recently wrote the following code for a [codewars.com kata for evaluating mathematical expressions](http://www.codewars.com/kata/evaluate-mathematical-expression/ruby).  I've been writing ruby for years,  but almost everything I do is for personal use and isn't shared, so I've gotten essentially zero feedback on my ruby style.  The following block of code (with more comments than usual) is fairly typical of my style, but it never feels as ruby-ish as the code snippets I see online.

What can be changed to make this code closer to ideal idiomatic ruby?

```
#parse the initial expression, break it up into an array 
# of tokens (numbers, parens, operations, etc)
# this also detects negation and cheges the symbol from '-' to 'n'
# and finally, this converts numbers to floats
def tokenize_expression(expression)
    #remove spaces
    s = expression.gsub(/\s/,'')

    #convert negations to 'n' character
    while md = s.match(%r{(?<![\d\)])-}) do
        s[md.begin(0)] = 'n'
    end

    #iterate through string
    #if number, get full number and add to array
    #otherwise grab just the first character which will be an operation or parenthesis
    tokens = []
    while not s.empty?
        if not s.match(%r{^\d}).nil?      #first char is digit
            md = s.match %r{[\d\.]+}
            s = md.post_match
            tokens << md[0].to_f
        else
            tokens << s[0]                #first char is parenthesis or operation
            s = s[1..-1]                  #everything but first char
        end
    end

    tokens
end


#take the array and make sub arrays based on the parentheses
# e.g. ['(', '1', '+', '(', '2', '+', '3', ')', ')'] -> ['1', '+', ['2', '+', '3']]
def nest_parens(tokens)
  result = []
  stack = []
  first, *rest = *tokens
  while not first.nil? do
    case first                            #look at first token
      when '('                          
        stack.push result                 #store current partial result on stack if open parens
        result = []                       #start new result
      when ')'
        child = result                    #store result in temp var
        result = stack.pop                #get previous partial result
        result << child                   #add temp result to current result
      else 
        result << first                   #add this token to the current result
    end    
    first, *rest = *rest
  end
  throw "Unclosed parenthesis" if not stack.empty?
  result
end

#find all the neagtions and convert them to nested postfix
# e.g. '5-n6' becomes '5-[n 6]'
def postfix_negation(tokens)
  return tokens if not tokens.is_a? Array
  tokens = tokens.map{ |t| postfix_negation(t) }    #recursively process everything below the current level

  result = []
  first, *rest = *tokens
  while not first.nil? 
    case first
      when 'n'
        second, *rest = *rest
        result << [first, second]         #e.g. [n 6]
      else
        result << first
    end
    first, *rest = *rest
  end
  result
end

#find all operations (mult/div or plus/minus) and convert to nested postfix
# e.g. '1+2*3' becomes '[+ 1 [* 2 3]]'
def postfix_ops(tokens, ops=['/','*'])
  return tokens if not tokens.is_a? Array
  tokens = tokens.map{ |t| postfix_ops(t, ops) }    #recursively process everything below the current level

  result = []
  first, *rest = *tokens
  while not first.nil?
    second = rest.first                   #if there is an operator, second will contain it
    if ops.include? second                          
      second, third, *rest = *rest
      first = [second, first, third]      #[op, arg1, arg2].  This now becomes first and is compared again to the following tokens,
      next                                #which will handle cases like 1+2+3  --> [+ [+ 1 2] 3]
    else
      result << first
    end

    first, *rest = *rest
  end
  result
end

#take a fully processed, postfix tree and recursively evaluate the expressions
def eval(tree)
  return tree if not tree.is_a? Array     #if this isn't an array, return it
  tree = tree.map {|n| eval(n) }          #recursively process everything below the current level
  return tree.first if tree.length == 1   #sometimes we end up with a single value as an array, e.g. [5], so just return the inner value
  first, second, third = tree             #process arguments
  case first
    when 'n' then return -second
    when '+' then return second + third
    when '-' then return second - third
    when '*' then return second * third
    when '/' then return second / third
    else raise "Unkown Op: #{first}"
  end  
end

#wrapper to call all the needed steps for processing
def calc(expression)
  tokens = tokenize_expression(expression)
  tokens = nest_parens(tokens)
  tokens = postfix_negation(tokens)
  tokens = postfix_ops(tokens, ['/','*'])
  tokens = postfix_ops(tokens, ['+','-'])
  eval(tokens)
end

#test input
[
"2/(2+3)*4", 
"2-(-(3*-2))",
"3*((4*5)*6*(7*8))",
"-(55--(-(1+2))--12)"
].each do |s|
    puts "\nString: #{s}"
    puts "Eval:   #{calc(s)}"
end
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the code, but I feel like you could use `.each` to iterate over lists instead of your `while`s...

Comment: @Caridorc I'm not advancing over the lists in an even fashion, sometimes I iterate over the same item multiple times, sometimes items are skipped

Comment: I understand, it is not so straightforward as it seems

Comment: If you are curious, you can add print statements between every line in calc() to see how the string is slowly converted to postifx (this was how I debugged it)

Comment: I've rolled your question back. Please read [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Single responsibility principle

```
#parse the initial expression, break it up into an array 
# of tokens (numbers, parens, operations, etc)
# this also detects negation and cheges the symbol from '-' to 'n'
# and finally, this converts numbers to floats
def tokenize_expression(expression)
```

Your function `tokenize_expression` does:

- break [the initial expression] up into an array
- detects negation and changes the symbol from '-' to 'n'
- converts numbers to floats

This should be three functions:

```
def negation_to_n(expression)
    s = expression.gsub(/\s/,'')
    while md = s.match(%r{(?<![\d\)])-}) do
        s[md.begin(0)] = 'n'
    end
    s
end


def split_tokens(expression)
    ### Implement
end

def numbers_to_floats(tokens)
    tokens.map{|t| t.match(%r{^\d}) ? t.to_f : t}
end
```

#### Use functional programming when practical

You should not feel forced to stick to imperative programming even when it becomes so hard to follow, for example `negation_to_n` can be written just like (please note that the string should be passed in already without spaces):

```
def matching_indexes(s, regex)
  s
   .enum_for(:scan, regex)
   .map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
end

def negation_to_n(s)
  (0...s.length)
    .map{|i| matching_indexes(s, %r{(?<![\d\)])-}).include?(i) ? 'n' : s[i]}
end
```

Another example is `split_tokens`:

```
def split_tokens(s)
  s
    .chars
    .chunk {|d| is_digit?(d)}
    .map{|_, xs| xs}
    .map {|g| g.all? {|ch| is_digit?(ch)} ? g.join : g}
    .flatten
end
```

Surely other parts can be similarly simplified.

Comment: I like what you have suggested with matching_indexes and negation_to_n.  I'm not really familiar with ".enum_for", so I'll have to look into incorporating that in the future.  I see what you are trying to suggest with break_into_array and numbers_to_floats but I question the usefulness.  Detecting the full number and breaking it out is the hard part and requires the bulk of the work.  Making a whole new function just to avoid appending ".to_f" on the end seems questionable.  I suppose the "to_f" could be added to the operands in eval, but it would look messy

Comment: I see where you are coming from: _Making a whole new function_ you feel like writing a function more is a chore or a difficulty, but I think that more functions make it easier to write code because you can test them one by one.

Comment: For what it's worth, tokenize_expression was originally a full class with a next_token() and to_a() methods, but it seemed like overkill and needlessly complicated, especially for purposes of soliciting feedback, so I merged it into a single function for posting.

Comment: I also like split_tokens(), now that you've added it.  I obviously need to spend some time learning Enumerable

Comment: @Zack to learn about how it works, you may add `.tap{|x| p x}` at the end of each line.

Comment: Instead of everything in your `split_token` method, might I suggest `s.scan /\d+|./`?

Comment: @Zack please don't simplify your code when posting here. We want your real code, precisely to avoid the "but my real code looks like this" comments. Imagine how you'd feel if you took the time to offer assistance to someone and they replied with that.

Comment: @Jordan Thanks for the tip, another advantage of writing many functions is that you can see simplifications more easily

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Code After Feedback

I've remodeled my code after Caridorc's example.  It took a lot of time to refactor the code, possibly longer than I spent writing it in the first place.  I'd guess it is a little more readable and idiomatic than it was before, although I'm not sure it was worth the time investment.  Regardless, I've at least learned several new ruby tricks out of all of this.  Any thought on new code?

```
def apply_negation_symbol(s)
  copy = s.clone
  s
    .enum_for(:scan, %r{(?<![\d\)])-})
    .map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
    .each { |ix| copy[ix] = 'n' }
  copy
end

def nest_parenthesis(s)
  stack = []
  s
    .chars
    .inject Array.new do |arr, char|
      case(char)
        when '(' then stack.push arr; Array.new
        when ')' then stack.pop << arr
        else arr << char
      end
    end
end

def is_numerical?(c)
  not (c =~ %r{[\d\.]}).nil?
end

def digits_to_floats(tree)
  return tree if not tree.is_a? Array
  tree = tree.map {|t| digits_to_floats(t) }
  tree
    .chunk {|d| is_numerical?(d)}
    .map{|_, xs| xs}
    .flat_map {|g| g.all? {|ch| is_numerical?(ch)} ? g.join.to_f : g}
end

def negation_to_postfix(tree)
  return tree if not tree.is_a? Array
  tree = tree.map{ |t| negation_to_postfix(t) }
  tree
    .slice_before{|item| item == 'n'}
    .flat_map { |arr| arr.first == 'n' ? [arr.first(2), arr[2..-1]] : arr}
    .delete_if { |item| item.is_a? Array and item.empty?}
end

def operations_to_postfix(tree, ops=['/','*'])
  return tree if not tree.is_a? Array
  tree = tree.map{ |t| operations_to_postfix(t, ops) }
  tree
    .map.with_index{ |item, ix| ops.include?(item) ? ix : nil}
    .compact
    .reverse
    .each do |ix|
      arg1, op, arg2 = tree.slice!(ix-1..ix+1)
      tree[ix-1] = [op, arg1, arg2]
    end
  tree
end

def calc(expression)
  s = apply_negation_symbol(expression)
  tree = nest_parenthesis(s)
  tree = digits_to_floats(tree)
  tree = negation_to_postfix(tree)
  tree = operations_to_postfix(tree, ops=['/','*'])
  tree = operations_to_postfix(tree, ops=['+','-'])
  eval(tree)
end
```

Comment: I don't want to be negative for the sake of being negative, but while this is more functional, which I like, I find it way less readable than your original code.

Comment: Those were more or less my feelings. Some of it is better, some of it is worse, and it took a whole lot of time. Changing negation_to_postfix() to use the same array replacement logic I used in operations_to_postfix() would help a little for readability, but altering arrays in place (even though it is a local variable) feels like it violates the spirit of functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

Overall I think your code is great. Almost zero WTFs. Of course, I wouldn't be posting if I didn't have suggestions. I've broken it up into methods below, with a "Miscellaneous" section at the end for general advice.

### tokenize_expression

I'll take this in two sections:

**Convert negations to `n`**

I think you overthought this part a bit. This:

```
#convert negations to 'n' character
while md = s.match(%r{(?<![\d\)])-}) do
    s[md.begin(0)] = 'n'
end
```

...is better expressed like this:

```
s.gsub!(/(?<![\d\)])-/, 'n')
```

**Consume tokens**

Your code:

```
while not s.empty?
    if not s.match(%r{^\d}).nil?      #first char is digit
        md = s.match %r{[\d\.]+}
        s = md.post_match
        tokens << md[0].to_f
    else
        tokens << s[0]                #first char is parenthesis or operation
        s = s[1..-1]                  #everything but first char
    end
end
```

Firstly, this line:

```
if not s.match(%r{^\d}).nil?
```

...would be better expressed as:

```
if s.match(/^\d/) # `nil` is falsey in Ruby
```

...but since you're not using the MatchData object returned by `match`, you should use the `=~` operator (it returns a Fixnum, which is always truthy, or `nil`):

```
if s =~ /^\d/
```

Secondly, this is a waste:

```
if not s.match(%r{^\d}).nil?      #first char is digit
    md = s.match %r{[\d\.]+}
    s = md.post_match
```

You're throwing away the MatchData object from the first line and then performing a very similar match on the second line. You can do this with one match operation:

```
if md = s.match(/^\d+(\.\d+)?/)
  s = md.post_match
```

This Regexp matches one or more digits optionally followed by a decimal point and one or more digits. (This also solves a bug in your code that would have matched `1.2.3` as a valid number.)

We can improve this further, though:

```
until s.empty?
  tokens <<
    if num = s.slice!(/^\d+(\.\d+)?/)
      num.to_f
    else
      s.slice!(0)
    end
end
```

Instead of matching the expression, checking the result, adding the matched part to `tokens` and setting `s` to everything after it, we do all of those things at once by passing the expression to [`String#slice!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-slice-21). If nothing is matched `slice!` returns `nil`, so we do `s.slice!(0)` to chop off just the first character instead.

Or further, although we're getting somewhat occult now:

```
while s.slice!(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?|(.)/)
  tokens << ($1 || $&.to_f)
end
```

This is basically the same except I've added an alternation that, if a number wasn't matched, captures the first character in capture group 1 (`$1`). If a number *was* matched, `$1` will be `nil` and so we call `to_f` on the whole match (`$&.to_f`).

### nest_parens

This method is really solid. I only have one suggestion, which is to use `Enumerable#reduce` or `Enumerable#each_with_object` instead of a `while` loop:

```
result = tokens.reduce([]) do |res, token|
  case token
    when '(' then stack.push(res); []
    when ')' then stack.pop << res
    else res << token
  end
end
```

#### postfix_negation

This one is also really solid. Unlike the above I don't think `reduce` works well here (since you're sometimes, but not always, consuming a second element).

One thing that's slightly smelly to me is having `first, *rest = tokens` before your loop and `first, *rest = rest` at the bottom:

```
first, *rest = *tokens
while not first.nil?
  case first
    when 'n'
      second, *rest = *rest
      result << [first, second]         #e.g. [n 6]
    else
      result << first
  end
  first, *rest = *rest
end
```

Also, I think a `case` expression is overkill when you only have one condition and an `else`. I'd probably rewrite your loop like this:

```
while first = tokens.shift
  if first == 'n'
    result << [ first, tokens.shift ]
  else
    result << first
  end
end
```

#### postfix_ops

Similar to the above:

```
while first = tokens.shift
  if ops.include?(tokens.first)
    second, third = tokens.shift(2)
    tokens.unshift([ second, first, third ])
  else
    result << first
  end
end
```

As you can see, I prefer `a, b = rest.shift(2)` to `a, b, *rest = rest`.

#### eval

Don't shadow `Kernel#eval`. I'd rename this method to `evaluate`.

Otherwise, this method is very good. One thing I'd do is remove all of the `return`s from your `case` expression. The `case` is the last expression in the method, so whichever `then` is reached will be the return value of the method:

```
case first
  when 'n' then -second
  when '+' then second + third
  # ...
  else raise "Unknown Op: #{first}"
end
```

If you want to get fancy, you could replace this with the following:

```
if first == 'n'
  first, second, third = 0, '-', second
end

first.send(second, third)
```

However, this way you lose error handling for unknown operators. You could add it back in simply enough, but by then it might not be worth it.

#### Miscellaneous

1. Use consistent indentation. Two spaces is standard for Ruby.
2. Don't use `do` after a `while` (or `for`). It's implied.
3. Use `unless` instead of `if not`.
4. `while not first.nil? do` should either be `while first` or `until first.nil?`. Similarly, I recommend `until s.empty?` instead of `while not s.empty?`.
5. You don't need the splat before `tokens` in `first, *rest = *tokens`, because `tokens` is already an array.
6. Regexp "percent notation" (`%r{...}`) is good for reducing visual noise when your expression contains slashes, because you don't have to escape them (`%r{a/b/c}` vs. `/a\/b\/c/`); however, when you don't have any slashes, I find it actually *adds* visual noise and prefer normal slash notation.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Jordan. A few of your suggestions I've already done on the improved code. Your suggestion about using gsub() for swapping out the negation symbol made me smack my forehead; I really overthought that one. With regards to Misc#5, the splat before tokens is required for what I want (a Lisp style first() and rest() destructuring); it doesn't work without it.  As for Misc #6, I left it %r{} to keep the regexes consistent, rather than mixing escape syntax.  Thank you again for your feedback

Comment: You're mistaken about the splat. Take a look: http://ideone.com/PtwYaQ A splat on the right-hand side of an assignment just invokes `to_ary`, on it; since `tokens` is an array this is a no-op.

Comment: Hmm. According to this article (http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/01/31/first-and-rest-in-ruby/), it was required for proper handling of empty lists, but maybe it's changed in more recent versions of ruby (which testing seems to confirm)